# .htaccess fake image

Tags: image, .htaccess

I currently have a system where I can go

```
<img src = "http://www.mydomain.com/assets/thumbnail.php?url=website_url_here/"/>
```

But the issue is, is the browser wont cache it because I will have multiple of these images on one page but just changing thr `url` variable.

So what I would like to do is use .htaccess to turn the url into

```
<img src = "http://www.mydomain.com/assets/thumbnail/website_url_here.png"/>
```

How could this be done?

Comment: Browsers will cache urls with get-variables just fine. This used to be a problem, but not anymore. So unless you PHP is setting some header that prevent caching, it should just work.

Answer (score 1):

You can add some mod_rewrite rules in the htaccess file in either your document root or in your `assets` directory. In your document root, they'd look something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?assets/thumbnail/([^.]+)\.(png|jpe?g|gif)$ /assets/thumbnail.php?url=$1.$2 [L,NC]
```

Or if the htaccess file is in the assets directory:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /assets/
RewriteRule ^thumbnail/([^.]+)\.(png|jpe?g|gif)$ thumbnail.php?url=$1.$2 [L,NC]
```